# WaitForExit default browser

Tags: c#, browser, process, processstartinfo, waitforexit

I'm using this code:

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
si.UseShellExecute = true;
si.FileName = Url;
p = Process.Start(si);
p.WaitForExit();
```

To open the "Url" in the default browser. I want to wait for the user to close that browser and then execute the code further. But after opening the Url in IE (my default browser), it throws an Object reference not set to an instance of object and highlights

```
p.WaitForExit();
```

What is the problem? I just want to wait until it finishes. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ProcessStartInfo.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename.aspx) gets or sets the application or document to start.
What I have done is passed the application path in the FileName so when Process.Start creates it looks for Arguments and creates an instance in your case it does not

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.StartInfo = si;
si.UseShellExecute = true;
si.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe";
si.Arguments = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                UseShellExecute = true,
                FileName = "http://google.com",                
            }).WaitForExit();
```

Comment: It gives me the following error: No process is associated with this object. on p.waitforexit();

Comment: Yes, that does not work for some reasons. I've edited my answer, this seems work.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I think it is because of Internet Explorer tabs separated in different process but still acting as only one app.